# dynamically add child tree node based on bindingsource

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes

I have an interesting question. I want to be able to access my bindingsource in vb.net through treeview. so each binding that I have will create a child node, by clicking that child node it will access that databinding and display it in gridview.

I used and modified this formula I found on this website:

```
enter code here Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each table As DataTable In DeathsDataSet.Tables
        Dim node As New TreeNode(table.TableName)

        If table.ParentRelations.Count = 0 Then
            TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(node)

        ElseIf table.ParentRelations.Count = 1 And table.ChildRelations.Count = 1 Then
            node.Tag = table.TableName
            node.Text = table.TableName
            TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(node)
        ElseIf table.ChildRelations.Count = 0 And table.ParentRelations.Count = 1 Then
            node.Tag = table.TableName
            node.Text = table.TableName
            TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(i).Nodes.Add(node)
            i += 1
        End If
    Next
```

I am able to get the child name from the table but then I have to go and use this:

```
enter code here   Sub treeView1_NodeMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick

    If e.Node.Text.Equals("Anderson") Then
        DataGridView1.DataSource = AndersonBindingSource
    End If
```

problem is that I have to use both instances to get the result I am looking for. I would like to dynamically make my nodes from my bindingsource, so for each new binding I have it will produce a linked child node.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious: store the BindingSource in the Tag?